# Exercise regarding proven a subset in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is manifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

$let\,S^{2}=\left\{ x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1\right\} \,\,and\,f:S^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R\,\,}is\,smooth\,funcion,such\,that\,f\left(\xi\right)\geq1\,\forall\xi\in S^{2}..\,\,\\define\,\,M=\left\{ f\left(\xi\right)\xi\,|\,\xi\in S^{2}\right\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^{3}\\a)prove\,that\,M\,is\,2-dim\,\,smooth\,\,mainfold\\b)prove\,that\,Area\left(S^{2}\right)\leq Area\left(M\right)$

I tried to define a map:
$\psi:V\rightarrow M,\,\psi\left(x\right)=r\left(x\right)\cdot f\left(r\left(x\right)\right)$

when (r,v) is a map into S^2. but I had problem proving this map is regular (rank(D_psi)=2)
I didnt managed to think about any other way to solve this.

Thank you very much!

peleg

Comment: Dear Peleg, you should try to use latex on MSE instead of adding images, it will be beneficial for you later.

Comment: ok thank you for telling me I will learn how to do this

Comment: For your question, you can show that $M$ and $\Bbb{S}^2$ are indeed diffeomorphic by noticing that: $g: \Bbb{R}^3\backslash \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ is a smooth map.

Comment: I correct my question so it is without images. thanks again! for which g are you reffering?